# How to release an locally created object, while it using as return object

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my pgm, i am getting a leak warning in this segment.

-(NSMutableArray *)filterArrayForBank:(NSMutableArray *)originalArray withKey:(NSString *)key{
NSMutableArray *mutableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

```
for (int i=0; i<[originalArray count]>0; i++) {
    if([[[originalArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"transType"] isEqualToString:key]){
        [mutableArray addObject:[originalArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
//////NSLog(@"mutableArray %@",mutableArray);
       return mutableArray ;
```

}

if i block this leak by below line, app get crash

either 
return [mutableArray autorelease];

or

NSMutableArray *mutableArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];

plz help me to stop this leak.
thanks in advance.

Comment: is memory leaking when you allocating this `NSMutableArray *mutableArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];` ?

Comment: @sherilyn, its not showing any leak, but application getting crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return an autoreleased array you need to make sure you retain it in the caller method. However, if you are not retaining it in the caller method, try renaming the method to:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)newFilterArrayForBank:(NSMutableArray *)originalArray withKey:(NSString *)key
```

This will notify the compiler that you are allocating a new NSMutableArray.

Comment: can you plz explain, changing the method will solve the problem?. I haven't retained in caller method.

Comment: @Ram If you want to return an owned object your method name should start with new. This will remove warning and is also good practice, since it's obvious from the method name that a new object is created.

Comment: Thanks man, i have made the changes and retained it in caller method. Now leak is stopped and no crashing. Once again Thanks!